# How do you use bugs to drive refactoring the code base?

Tags: automated-testing

How do you use the bugs that you find while testing to get more attention to refactoring and improving the overall code base and re-writing particularly troublesome sections of code that have been proven as buggy, hard-to-maintain or poorly written?

Comment: What does "bring bugs to the surface" mean?

Comment: Gave it a go to make it a usable question.  OP will need to see if that's what they meant / they are comfortable with the new question.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider establishing unit tests (NUnit,XUnit,JUnit,etc...) in more troublesome places (or a seperate project) and once sufficient tests are in place inact some form of continuous integration to auto-run the tests in some form of pre-commit hook.
Using Jenkins for example, you can track some metrics which will give you some fire power on the importance of refactoring poorly written code.
In other words, you want to be able to say confidently "X hours are spent monthly fixing bugs in location A. The total number of bugs found in location A is Y. Therefore, I recommend fixing location A."